# Renting LEGO Service in UK

Tags: afol

Has anyone used the LEGO rental service, www.letsgoplay.co.uk? I'm not quite an AFOL, but I do enjoy building the larger sets, and although it would be great to keep some of them long term I just don't have the space or cash to buy them all. Seems like a pretty good deal and they list some pretty rare sets.

Comment: Hi Paul, and welcome to LEGO Answers. We're a little different here in that we're [not a discussion site](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/tour) but are a Q&A site - we're great at answering questions that have clear, definitive answers. Do you have a specific question about letsgoplay.co.uk (for example quality of customer service, etc.) that isn't covered by their site already?